# Stretching vertical layout with header and footer of static height in plain HTML/CSS

Tags: html, layout, xhtml, css

What is the simplest way bo build vertical layout where header and footer have static height and the center occupies all available space (and adjusts to the window height).

```
header
------

center


------
footer
```

Thanks for help

ps Absolute positioning is not an option for me.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/smHxe/

Comment: Yes but center should use all available height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smHxe/1/)

Use margins to set the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of the middle `<div>` to `-50px`, or whatever the respective height of your desired header and the footer is.

Alternatively use this (relatively hacky) method if you want to add content to the middle part of the page. 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smHxe/3/)

Answer (score 1):

jacktheripper's answer does work, but I do not advise it! Cross-browser compatibility may not be just. Do think a look at Ryan Fait's "Sticky Footer". It can be found [here](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). There's another one out there, namely ['CSS Sticky Footer'](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html), but I haven't used it. Should work relatively the same and you don't need a 'push div'. Be sure to read the 'Known Issues' on [this](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) page though!